# Vuex - loading many tables - chain a bunch of await dispatch fetches?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, fetch, vuex

I'm newish to Vue and hacking my way through loading a  bunch of tables asynchronously.

Is there a more concise / efficient way of composing this?

```
initializeApp({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
  commit("initializeStore"); // sets userData from localStorage || ""
  if (state.userData.token) {
    dispatch("getTables");
  }
},
async getTables({ dispatch, commit }) {
  await dispatch("getCollections");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Merchants");
  commit("setMerchants", payload);
},
async getCollections({ dispatch, commit }) {
  await dispatch("getCategories");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Collections");
  commit("setCollections", payload);
},
async getCategories({ dispatch, commit }) {
  await dispatch("getSubLocations");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Categories");
  commit("setCategories", payload);
},
async getSubLocations({ dispatch, commit }) {
  await dispatch("getLocations");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("SubLocations");
  commit("setSubLocations", payload);
},
async getLocations({ dispatch, commit }) {
  await dispatch("getQualities");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Locations");
  commit("setLocations", payload);
},
async getQualities({ dispatch, commit }) {
  await dispatch("getUserRoles");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Qualities");
  commit("setQualities", payload);
},
async getUserRoles({ dispatch, commit}) {
  await dispatch("getPreviousRoomScans");
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("User Roles");
  commit("setUserRoles", payload);
},
async getPreviousRoomScans({ commit }) {
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Room Scans");
  commit("setPreviousRoomScans", payload);
},
```

Comment: Hey, do you mind explaining more in depth what you want to achieve? First of all in my opinion writing actions like this, on action triggering a chain of actions is not a good practice, since they act like a singular function anyways, you could just include them in a single function if you have written them like this, but you could expain what you want to achieve and we could help you better, there is not enough data in your question for me to give an objectively good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions surely shouldn't chain each other like that, unless an action specifically depends on the result from previous action.

`initializeApp` doesn't await for actions it dispatches, which prevents it from be chained correctly by a caller.

For independent actions that should be dispatched on initialization, a common recipe is:

```
initializeApp({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
  commit("initializeStore");
  if (state.userData.token) {
    await Promise.all([
      dispatch("getTables"),
      ...
    ]);
  }
},
async getTables({ commit }) {
  const payload = await airtableQuery.getTableAsync("Merchants");
  commit("setMerchants", payload);
},
...
```